# How to Search on Joined Tables with multiple column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting errors saying t.product_id column is unknown.
I used this code:

```
SELECT
    t.product_id as ID,
    product_category as Category,
    product_name As Product,
    product_price as Price,
    product_decription as Description,
    t.Stats as 'Status',
    tblinventory.quantity
FROM tblproduct as t
INNER JOIN tblinventory
    on t.product_id = tblinventory.product_id
WHERE 
    CONCAT(`t.product_id`,`product_category`,`product_name`,`t.Stats`) LIKE '%"2"%'
```

I just cant seem to make it work.
tblproduct has columns product_id,product_category,product_name,product_price,product_description and stats

while tblinventory has columns product_id and quantity

Comment: Please include your table definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the `t.product_id` refers to a column with that name -- "t.product_id" rather than the column `product_id` in the table `t`.  Remove the escape characters:

```
WHERE CONCAT(t.product_id, product_category, product_name, t.Stats) LIKE '%"2"%'
```

You don't need to escape the names, so don't.

Comment: I've already tried that earlier, it works but returns no data

Comment: My guess is that nothing matches.  If you are looking for `2`, then use `like '%2%'` -- remove the double quotes.

Comment: removing the double quotes works, and it works in other columns now too. thanks